# Django second level annotate query different table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this query:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(flag=False)\
.annotate(task_count=Count('task'))\
.filter(task__disabled=True)\
.annotate(tasks=DistinctConcat('task__name', separator=';'))\
.values('id', 'task_count', 'tasks')
```

Where I want to get something like:

```
{
    'id': u'0bac989c-1396-11e5-83ed-0242aa110587',
    'tasks': u'task1;task20;task23',
    'task_count': 35
}
```

where `task_count` is 35 because it counts every task related to `MyModel.id="0bac989c-1396-11e5-83ed-0242aa110587"`, and `tasks` shows a list of `disabled` tasks (`disabled` is a field of the `task` Model).

Instead, with my query I am getting a list in `tasks` with the full list of all 35 tasks.

I first started with:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(flag=False, task__disabled=True)
.annotate(task_count=Count('task'), tasks=DistinctConcat('task_name', separator=';'))
.values('id', 'task_count', 'tasks')
```

Which doesn't work because it gets:

```
{
    'id': u'0bac989c-1396-11e5-83ed-0242aa110587',
    'tasks': u'task1;task20;task23',
    'task_count': 3
}
```

there, `task_count` is counting the current list on the query, which I don't want, **because I want the list of `disabled` tasks but the complete count of all related tasks on `0bac989c-1396-11e5-83ed-0242aa110587`.**

Please help

---

BTW, the `GroupConcat` I am using is:

```
class SQLDistinctConcat(SQLAggregate):
    sql_function = 'group_concat'

    @property
    def sql_template(self):
        separator = self.extra.get('separator')
        if separator:
            return '%(function)s(DISTINCT %(field)s separator "%(separator)s")'
        else:
            return '%(function)s(DISTINCT %(field)s)'


class DistinctConcat(Aggregate):
    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        aggregate = SQLDistinctConcat(
            col, source=source, is_summary=is_summary, **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate
```